# Windows 10 Auto-Logon issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, autologin

We've discovered a strange issue, possibly a new bug with our domain Windows 10 devices.

Quick and dirty; Domain devices requiring AutoAdminLogon work fine, EXCEPT for one model device, Dell 3020m

DETAILS:

We use the same Windows 10 image (version 1703 build 15063.726), deployed via MDT for every device in our office.

A few devices used randomly by multiple persons require AutoLogon (please omit 'security issue' responses, we are aware...)

Recently we re-imaged a Dell 3020m to be Win10 and setup the auto-logon and we are met with this:

https://i.imgur.com/V8a3iC7.png

Instead of logging in (as any other model device) we get this 'Phone number or email' prompt. ONLY only the Optiplex 3020m do we see this. We've verified the REG:

https://i.imgur.com/ThgLY5l.png

The REG is identical to a verified working device (obviously, credentials are 'fake' for security reasons)

And here's the kicker: If we set AutoAdminLogon to 0, the 'Phone or email' prompt goes away, but of course it also doesn't log on.

Do ANY of you know what would cause this on the Dell Optiplex 3020m?

----Additional Information----

Works fine on these devices:: Dell Optiplex 7020 - 5040 - 5050 ---AND--- Dell Latitude e5440 - e5470 - 5480

We have tried 8 different user accounts

Verified that these devices are not in any different OU than the other models

These are all DOMAIN devices, therefore control userpassword2/netplwiz will not work to store credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Different performance characteristics may cause this. Could be on that problematic Dell, network stack starts up too slow, so by the time Windows is trying to auto-login, networking is not yet available. Autologin fails because there’s no connection to a domain controller, and you see the login prompt instead.

Windows event logs might contain more info.

**Update** Here’s what I would do.

1. Reproduce that error on that problematic Dell PC.
2. Note the exact time when you restarted the PC and it failed to auto-login.
3. Log in manually as a local administrator (if the PC is in domain, any domain admin is also a local admin).
4. Read system and security windows event logs, start from the system one. Scroll to that time, see if there’re any interesting errors or warnings.

I don’t know what’s wrong with your Dells, but in my experience troubleshooting all kinds of weird stuff with Windows, very often system event logs just tells you what’s wrong. If you see something weird you don't understand, search the Internet for source + event ID combo, e.g. "Source DNS Client Events Event ID 1014"

Comment: I didnt' see anything, but then again i wasn't looking for network information.. That's somewhere to start at least, thanks

Comment: @JustaCaffinatedmachine You're welcome. See the update.